# Kendo grid search panel sometimes updates and sometimes not

Tags: javascript, gridview, datagridview, kendo-ui, grid

I have a grid, I added the method to insert the search panel and when entering the search information sometimes it does the filtering well, but sometimes I have a grid, I added the method to insert the search panel and when entering the search information sometimes it does the filtering well.
But sometimes, even if there is information that matches, it leaves the grid.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.